# Serialize message with unsupported C++ types in protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Since protobuf does not allow serialization of `int8_t`, `int16_t` and some other c++ types, I have made the following message for those:

```
message OtherType
{
    enum Type 
    {
        CHAR = 0;// Default
        INT8 = 1;
        INT16 = 2;
        UINT8 = 3;
        UINT16 = 4;
    }
    Type type = 1;
    int32 value = 2;
}

message arrayOfNotSupportedTypes
{
    repeated OtherType value = 1;
}
```

Now, I may send big amounts of this type of data, e.g. pictures serialized to `uint8_t`. My question is: Does this approach of having this type of message with the message itself + type tag + value incur a lot of overhead, compared to have a message of just repeated `int32` like this:

```
message PlainArray
{
    repeated int32 value = 1;
}
```

I suppose I could use the second option instead of the first one for types that are not supported and just treat all non-supported values as `int32_t` after deserialization, if the overhead in the first approach is too big...

EDIT: I know that protobuf is not good for messages larger than 1MB, and if I have a large message , I will of course split it into smaller ones.

Comment: What do you hope to gain from this?  Your solution still sends `int32` across the wire no matter the actual type.

Comment: It will be easier to parse the message on the receiver side., since I know if the type is an int8_t or char.

Comment: If you need to send `repeated char`s, why not make it `string` or `bytes`?

Comment: It would be best if you describe what kind of data you are sending (from high level perspective). For example is it a path or count of cards or type of object or .... . Then how this fits to your solution. Basically this smells like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).